# How to connect two different ViewModels in Kotlin AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have two different View Models with their own fragments, and I want my arrayListB in ViewModelB have the same value of my arrayListA in ViewModelA.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this may help you to do that!

Architecture Components provides ViewModel helper class for the UI controller that is responsible for preparing data for the UI. ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance. For example, if you need to display a list of users in your app, make sure to assign responsibility to acquire and keep the list of users to a ViewModel, instead of an activity or fragment, as illustrated by the following sample code:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<User>>().also {
        loadUsers()
    }
}

fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return users
}

private fun loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
}
}
```

for more information see this :

(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?msclkid=bf393d12ce9011eca291710e2d69c5af)